# How to calculate the following exponential logic in the trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, controller, math

How to calculate exponential in trigger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert formula to APEX trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49907/how-can-i-convert-formula-to-apex-trigger)

Comment: Hi @Sanjana. Are you trying to understand how to do mathematical operations in a trigger? Or are you wondering how the control flow of a trigger works for this type of formula. If the latter, check out this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49907/how-can-i-convert-formula-to-apex-trigger?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

your formula `MarketValue$ =(Price__c* CMValue) / ((1 + Discount)^Contract)` is not equal to expression: `(50,000*.1)/((1 + .08)^1 + (50,000*.1)/((1 + .08)^2 = $8,916.32`

---

If you want to implement expression in apex, you can do it by means of [Math](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm) apex class:

```
Double price = 50000;
Double cmValue = 0.1;
Double coef = 1;
Double discount = 0.08;
Double contract = 2;
Double marketValue = (price * cmValue) / Math.pow(1 + discount, coef)  + ((price * cmValue) / Math.pow((1 + discount), contract));
System.debug('marketValue:' + marketValue);
```

and result is:

> |DEBUG|marketValue:8916.323731138546